# Axios requests in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I had a question days ago, let's imagine we have the following 3 promises:

```
let promise1 = axios.get(URL1);
let promise2 = axios.get(URL2);
let promise3 = axios.get(URL3);
```

They will execute asynchronously and return the data with `.then()`, and let's suppose each of these GET requests take 1.00 seconds.

The total execution of this requests will take 3 seconds right? Is there any way to execute this requests in parallel so that we get the data of the 3 requests in 1 second? Or it's impossible because of the single-threaded language?

Thank you.

Comment: you only get 3 seconds if you wait for each execution to finish... use `Promise.all()` to run them in parallel

Comment: i think easiest way to achive this is using async/await, google it i am not quite sure how exactly to do it, but i am sure it possible

Comment: https://techbrij.com/javascript-async-await-parallel-sequence

Comment: The requests shown get made in parallel. The creation of the promises is relatively instantaneous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [May 27, 2020](https://github.com/axios/axios/commit/d35b5b5902f72305216f245cc58bc2231470fb19), you should use `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([axios.get(URL1), axios.get(URL2), axios.get(URL3)])
    .then((responses) => {
        const [url1rest, url2resp, url3resp] = responses;
        // do something
    });
```

Now deprecated: you can use `axios.all` in conjunction with `axios.spread`:

```
axios.all([axios.get(URL1), axios.get(URL2), axios.get(URL3)])
     .then(axios.spread(url1resp, url2resp, url3resp) {
          // do something
     });
```

Comment: Theoretically this will take 1 second to complete the 3 requests?

Comment: It runs them concurrently, so yes if each request takes one second, then the whole thing should only take one second.

Comment: axios documentation says .all() is deprecated and asks directs to Promise.all instead (https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency-deprecated)

Answer (score 5):

The code you have **will** execute them in parallel. That's the point of asynchronous functions.

While JavaScript runs on a single event loop (unless you use Workers), asynchronous code is not bound by that loop. That's why the code is asynchronous in the first place.

The responsibility for making the HTTP requests is handed off to code outside of the event loop. This means it can execute in parallel.