# How to make 2 Axios requests for 1 page with middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

It is required to make 2 different requests for one page using middleware. 
The first thing that comes to mind is something like this: 
(I understand that 2 returns look pretty dumb.)

```
export default function ({$axios, req, store, route}) {

  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {

      console.log('111');

      return $axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + route.params.tracking.toLowerCase(), {})
          .then(response => {
              store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });


  }

  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {

      console.log('222');

      return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_status" , {
         })
        .then(response => {
            store.commit('tracking/setTrackingStatus', response.data.data.tracking_status);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

  }

}
```

Next, look at the console in Firebug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

We can observe on the screenshot - only the first request is triggered. 
(`console.log('111');`)
Question:
How to correctly, from the point of view of syntax and design, release a conceived idea?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `axios.all` in conjunction with `axios.spread`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066175/687137

Comment: I don't understand - how should I use 3 different 'store.commit' in this case?
should I use it into 'spread' body?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const R1='/requestAPI';
    const R2='/requestAPI';
    try{
       axios.all([
          this.$axios.get(`${R1}`),
          this.$axios.get(`${R2}`),
        ])
            .then(axios.spread((R1,R2) => {
                store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData',R1); //or set  the value to your data
                store.commit('tracking/setTrackingStatus',R2); //or set  the value to your data

            }));
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
```

**Note:**

- notice the order of R1 and R2  in **all** ,**spread**  and **then**
- i've predefined the base url of axios in `nuxt.config.js`  you can do that or `import axios`  and use `axios.get('fullUrl')` instead of `this.$axios.get()`

Comment: I wrote this: 
http://joxi.ru/EA4dWyzHOnbvwA
But I've got an error.
http://joxi.ru/n2YLbPaHZwM7Zm

Comment: You should use R1.data.data.tracking_data instead of  response.data.data.tracking_data  cause you defined  it's name R1 in the spread   and the same thing with the second request, use R2.data.data.tracking_status instead of response.data.data.tracking_status

Comment: Try : console.log(R1) and console.log(R2) to make sure you get a response form the api's

Comment: http://joxi.ru/E2p3KO1HawKj4m 
the same result,
http://joxi.ru/J2bxbPVcGl3MMr

Comment: No it's different one  try to import axios   above your export default  like this :          import  axios from "axios";   and use axios instead of this.$axios

Comment: axios.get(`${R1}`),
      axios.get(`${R2}`),

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Y2LlMPYCQbRv12
the same error.
http://joxi.ru/eAOEBPYtpdJG5m

Comment: Replace this.axios.get(${R1}), this.axios.get(${R2}),  with axios.get(${R1}), axios.get(${R2}),

Comment: http://joxi.ru/YmEgJPahJvg9JA
error
http://joxi.ru/E2p3KO1HawKV4m

Comment: Now the error  changed , so here what to do ... Try to remove the store.commit for now and use the middle ware in a page with no logic then open  this page then open the console  the responses of the requests will be there then you can start debugging your code from there.